# How may one suggest improvements on a tag wiki?

Tags: support, tags, editing, suggested-edits

How may one suggest improvements on a tag wiki?

E.g. the name of Huygens in the [aether](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aether) tag description is spelled Huygen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the 'improve tag info' button on the tag's page (e.g. [aether](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aether)) to edit. (Requires 100 reputation points.)