# Tag with no tag wiki description which should be merged

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

I just [discovered there is a floating](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/415471/) (no tag wiki description) [elementary-particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-particles) tag, which description is included in the [particle-physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-physics) tag. Should not these be merged?

Comment: The fact that the tag has no description doesn't really matter. If we decide not to merge it, we can always add a description later. But whether it should be merged is a good question.

Comment: Generally speaking, suggestions for tag synonyms should go [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/175/2451).

Comment: I agree the tags should be merged.

Answer (score 2):

1. The [particle-physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-physics) tag (currently with approx. 3500 questions) is one of a few primary tags. Ideally all questions should be tagged with a primary tag.
2. The [elementary-particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-particles) tag (currently with approx. 200 questions) is a secondary tag. It is mainly used for [particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_physics) questions where it is important to distinguish between [elementary particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle) and composite particles.

   *Example:* Phys.SE often gets [questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39590/2451) about whether the electron is an elementary particle or not.

   For this role the tag [elementary-particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-particles) does serve some purpose, and seems worth keeping.
3. A related secondary tag is the [point-particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/point-particles) tag (currently with approx. 100 questions). Note that the notion of [point-particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_particle) is used also outside the area of [particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_physics), e.g. in [classical mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_mechanics).
4. Concerning tag-wikis: Many tags lack tag-wikis. Users are encouraged to [create/improve](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10247/2451) them. There is even a [research assistant](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/87/research-assistant) badge for it.

Comment: The trouble is that it is not easy to find the tag and see if there is a new question not answered. Is there an easy way to find tags?

Comment: @anna v: The SE search engine is admittedly not optimal. If you e.g. want to find all tags containing the word 'particle', you might want to try typing the word 'particle' into the search box on the [tag homepage](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags).

Comment: Thanks, this helps as I try to answer if I can  elementary particle questions